# Changing database design after creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

I have an existing database with a number of columns. One of these is "Language" which indicates the language of the other data in the row.

The design I wish to implement would be simple to edit, if the database did not already have a couple of thousand of rows in it.

What I wish to do is select all the distinct languages (english, spanish, french, quenya...) - we can assume these are all in lower case and put this data into its own table.

The table I wish to create will be structured simply :

```
Language ID    |   Language   |   Shorthand for language
1              |    English   |    en-us
```

I then wish to edit my original table, and, in place of the "Language" column (which I will delete), I wish to put in the number of the corresponding language ID.

So, for example, an English row will look like :

```
IrrelevantInfo   |   LanguageID
foobar           |     1
```

Is it possible for me to do this without losing all of my data ?

Comment: Why not just leave the existing data as 'english', 'french' etc. and make this the primary key of your new table instead of 1, 2, 3?

Comment: @TonyAndrews e.g. The name of the language can be inconsistent (German vs Deutch vs Allemagne vs Германски) even if they are consistent now.

Comment: OK, but if they are consistent now and you make them a foreign key to your new table then they weill be forced to be consistent in future too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely.

Something like this should work:

```
CREATE TABLE Languages (id int identity NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
                        [Language] varchar(100), 
                        Shorthand varchar(100))

BEGIN TRAN -- We do a transaction here to ensure consistency

INSERT INTO Languages ([Language])
SELECT DISTINCT [Language]
FROM MySourceTable

-- Update the shorthands later


ALTER TABLE MySourceTable
ADD LanguageID int 
FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Languages(id)

UPDATE t
SET LanguageID = l.id
FROM MySourceTable T
INNER JOIN Languages l
    ON l.[Language] = t.[Language]

ALTER TABLE MySourceTable
DROP [Language]

COMMIT TRAN
```

I would also strongly recommend adding an index on the `LanguageId` field, and rebuilding all your indexes, especially the clustered index.  Adding and removing columns wreaks havoc on the fragmentation of your table and indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is possible.

1. Create the new language table.
2. Insert the distinct languages from your existing table to the language table.
3. Add the column `LanguageID` to your existing table.
4. Update `LanguageID` in the existing table using the language table with a join on column `language`.
5. Remove the column `language` from your existing table.